# Creating a list of sums of column values multiplied by another list returns a KeyError

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'm attempting to manually calculate fitted values from a multiple linear regression model by multiplying the real values of a pandas dataset by the corresponding coefficients, summing them for each row, and appending them to a list. Now I'm not particularly good in Python but I attempted to do it through two for loops, the first one iterating over a row, setting the current sum to the intercept value, and entering the second for loop which iterates through columns of the current row. In this one I tried to increase the current sum by the product of column value and the coefficient. Afterwards, the current sum is appended to the list x. However, executing the code always results in **KeyError: 0**.

```
        import pandas as pd
        from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
        #finaldata_y dataset contains real Y values, finaldata_x dataset contains real x values
        model = LinearRegression()
        model.fit(finaldata_x, finaldata_y)
        x = []
        for i in finaldata_y.index:
            xvalue = model.intercept_
            for j in range(len(finaldata_x.columns)):
                xvalue = xvalue + model.coef_[j] * finaldata_x[j][i]
            x.append(xvalue)
```

Am I forgetting something trivial here? Better yet, is there a way to do this through a function? I attempted to find a solution to my problem, but to no avail.

Comment: It would be helpful to show a minimum example - provide a sample input and what you expect output to look like.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to predict finaldata_x using your trained model, you can use the 'predict' method:

```
predict_y = model.predict(finaldata_x)
```